# PyDev code analysis not working properly

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, pydev

I'm having a problem with PyDev and Eclipse. This first happened with some old EasyEclipse version I had. I thought it was just because the EasyEclipse install was old, but it's now also happening with Eclipse 4.2.1 and PyDev 2.7.1. I'm running Python 2.7.3.

The problem is the type-time code analysis seems to be faulty or running the wrong Python version. It thinks this line has a syntax error:

```
x = 1 if some_boolean else 2
```

It's expecting a newline instead of the if-keyword. When running the module it works as expected.

This is very annoying as this one error seems to mess up further code analysis that would actually be useful. I'm not sure if it has something to do with the problem, but [this](http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html) site instructed me to try running the interpreterInfo.py, so [here](http://pastie.org/5056532) is the XML dump it generated.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm using PyDev 2.7.1 too, and code analysis has no problems here with the line `x = 1 if True else 2`. I guess that's one down.

Comment: Still, rendering an `if` / `else` clause this way doesn't seem good coding style. Is there a reason you cannot use `if some_boolean:` `x = 1` `else:` `x = 2`?

Answer (score -3):

Go to Project -> Properties, click on PyDev - Interpreter/Grammar, and then choose 2.7 in the "Grammar Version" drop-down.